# How to update the excel file cell data, when the file is created using a template in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am creating a new excel file using a template file, but I am unable to edit the contents in the new file created, please assist with the same. 
Thanks in advance.

````
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(fileStream))
{
     package.Save();
}

string name = "filecreated.xlsx";
string fileType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
fileStream.Position = 0;

//return file 
return File(fileStream, fileType, name);```
````

Comment: FileAccess.Read?

Comment: It seems like you are opening the file in read only access mode 
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

Answer (score 0):

It Seems like you are opening the file in read only access mode

> FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open,
>   FileAccess.Read);

Will you please try like

```
FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(filepath);
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
{
  //As we have not modified the file, its useless to call Save()

  //This will override the opened file
  package.Save();
}
```